# How to get line and column text with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I would like to know how to get the row and column of a text using itext in java.The files have objects and images that excludes the text order. I need to organize the structure of the text after extraction.

Comment: What do you mean by *row and column of a text*? Do you mean the coordinates?

Comment: Yes @mlk, exactly.

Comment: I'm problem last text first column. [look this example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6veYnYy4xq_dHlXRlRjd2hMRVU)

Comment: Unfortunately an image is of no help here. But at least it indicates that you have multicolumn document content which may make things a bit more complicated.

Comment: @mkl i only get coordinates xy string text using itext. You know how do ?

Comment: You already do get the coordinates and the text chunk there and need more? Or you don't get the coordinates yet and want to know how to get them?